# .map() is not defined as a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to use ".map()" to map documents which I'm getting from firebase.
However it says .map() is not a function. Code is below.
Basically I'm trying to fetch my firebase data, then render each doc as a element.

```
 <div{posts.map((doc) => <p>{doc.data().text}</p>)}</div>
```

How I decleared useState posts variable:

```
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
```

How I set useState posts variable:

```
useEffect(() => {
  db.collection('posts').onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
    setPosts(querySnapshot);

  });
})
```

Also, I tried using ".forEach". I can "console.log" the each documents by using ".forEach" but ".forEach" doesn't allow to return **elements**.

Comment: Also, the "posts" usestate variable is set like this: useEffect(() => {
      ref.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        setPosts(querySnapshot);

      });
  })

Comment: I have reedited it now, please check.

Comment: like how?
how the posts useState is defined and how you are assigning values to posts ?.

Comment: Please add code related to posts. Which declares is posts and changes it

Comment: @sojin and Tushar Shahi, I have reedit it please check.

Comment: most probably your `querySnapshot` is not an array. debug or log `querySnapshot` then you'll find out

Comment: It is an array when I .forEach it.

Comment: console or debug your `querySnapshot` and check what value are getting there

Comment: I noticed that the <div> tag in the first code block wasn't closed. Is it closed in the code you ran?

Answer (score 0):

first log your querySnapshot and see whether it's an array, then you should check if posts' array is not null. try this :

```
<div{posts.length > 0 ? posts.map((doc) => <p>{doc.data().text}</p>) : null}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.forEach` can be used over `Sets, Maps` and `Arrays`, whereas `.map` can be used only over arrays. So, it is likely that the `querySnapshot` is returning a set that is updated on `posts`, since `posts` is now a `Set`, `map` is unable to iterate and return values from the iterable `posts`. To overcome this, you could convert the Set to an array before updating the state.

```
useEffect(() => {
  db.collection('posts').onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
    let querySnapshotToArray = Array.from(querySnapshot)
    setPosts(querySnapshotToArray);

  });
})
```

Now that the `post` is an array, you could map over it and return the required values.

Answer (score 0):

when react component render the first time **posts** is `null` or  `undefined` so `.map` was **undefined** you need to use Optional chaining, represented by `?.` in JavaScript, which is a new feature introduced in ES2020.

```js
 <div{posts?.map((doc) => <p>{doc?.data()?.text}</p>)}</div>
```

Comment: As can be seen from the `useState` call where `posts` is assigned, `posts` is initialized to an empty list, and is thus neither `null` nor `undefined`.